Is an invalid date considered the same as a NULL value?
I am using MySQL 5.7 and I have notice something which I cannot explain to myself with my current knowledge so here it goes.
Is an "invalid" date 0000-00-00 considered same as NULL for a date column type with no possibilities for nullables? See the following example:

create table if not exists example
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    doskip date default '0000-00-00' not null
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES(1, '0000-00-00'), (2, '0000-00-00'), (3, '0000-00-00');

Having the above and running the following queries gave me the exact same count: 3 and I wonder why, is there any explanation for this?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example j WHERE j.doskip = '0000-00-00';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example j WHERE j.doskip IS NULL;

Here is a Fiddle showing this behavior, is it because of the mode?

Welcome to the wonderful world of MySQL! :-)


Is an invalid date considered the same as a NULL value?

From my understanding, 0000-00-00 on a date datatype column it is considered as a NULL.
From Problems Using DATE Columns

MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy
date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values.
If a date to be stored in a DATE column cannot be converted to any
reasonable value, MySQL stores '0000-00-00'. To disallow '0000-00-00',
enable the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.

In above statement isn't specifically mentioned that 0000-00-00 is treated as NULL, but I guess somewhere in the code it has to.
Another statement from the docs

The special “zero” date '0000-00-00' can be stored and retrieved as
'0000-00-00'. When a '0000-00-00' date is used through Connector/ODBC,
it is automatically converted to NULL because ODBC cannot handle
that kind of date

Note, this applies to date and datetime datatype, not timestamp

My suggestion
Fix the table design by making doskip date default  null since doskip date default '0000-00-00' not null doesn't make any sense anyway. Enable NO_ZERO_DATE with strict mode , replace all values from '0000-00-00' to NULL.
NULL is considered an unknow value and it can only be evaluated by using is null/is not null. 0000-00-00 is considered an unknown date (not an unknown value , thats why is not null count  gives 3 rows ) and that's why developers might have applied same null rules.

'0000-00-00' is a magic marker that is both "null" and "not null" simultaneously. You can extend your fiddle with:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example j WHERE j.doskip IS NOT NULL;

or even:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example j WHERE j.doskip IS NULL AND j.doskip IS NOT NULL;

The latter is a contradiction, yet all rows qualify. You can bring some sanity into older versions of MySQL by setting sql_mode to  NO_ZERO_DATE. While you are at it, also add ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
Another indication that it does not behave like null is that
j.doskip = j.doskip

evaluates to TRUE, whereas:
j.doskip <> j.doskip

evaluates to FALSE. You can try with:
select id, j.doskip=j.doskip, j.doskip<>j.doskip from example j;

MySQL 8 has improved a lot compared to the older versions. You may consider upgrading if you want to avoid these kinds of quirks
